# Laravel route with optional parameter to controller

Tags: laravel-4, routes, optional-parameters

A route with optional parameter works when doing like this:

```
Route::get('{anything}',function($anything){echo $anything;});
```

but I would like to use a controller. Doing like this produces an error:

```
Route::get('{anything}','redirectController');
```

controller:

```
class redirectController {

public function index($anything){
    echo $anything;
}}
```

What may be the problem? (using laravel 4.2)

**update**: 
I renamed the controller with capital letter, and tried this:

```
Route::get('{anything}',['uses' => 'RedirectController@index']);
```

but it's still an error: "Call to undefined method RedirectController::getAfterFilters() ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a controller there're two options:

1. `Route::controller('route', 'SomeController');`
2. `Route::get('route', ['uses' => 'SomeController@index']);`;

In the first case you have to read this:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers

Name of your action in this case should be `getIndex`, not just `index`.

Good luck!

**UPD**

Make sure your controller extends Laravel's Controller class like follows:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class SomeController extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So the controller function should be 'getIndex'?. I tried Route::get('{anything}',['uses' => 'RedirectController@index']);   but it didn't work..

Comment: 'RedirectController@index' means that it will use `RedirectController` and call `index` (not `getIndex` in this case) action. Make sure that your class name is `RedirectController` but not `redirectController` because class names by convention should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Okay, I renamed it. using just 'index' , it still doesn't work for me

Comment: See the UPD part of the answer. I highly recommend you to read documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! " extends BaseController" solved it. I'm very new to laravel, I have to admit.